# Weird behavior of re.sub with utf-8 strings

Tags: python, regex, encoding

Could anyone explain me this strange behavior? I would expect both replace methods to work or not to work at the same time. Is it just me or is there anyone who doesn't find this to be coherent?

```
>>> u'è'.replace("\xe0","")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> re.sub(u'è','\xe0','',flags=re.UNICODE)
''
```

(Please note that I'm not asking for an explanation of why u'è'.replace("\xe0","") raises an error!)

Comment: `unicode.replace` is not the same method as `re.sub`.

Comment: Of course. And my point is that they should behave coherently for the same inputs.

Comment: It's questions like these that led to the stricter enforcement of Unicode vs. Byte strings in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

From [Unicode Doc](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)

> the arguments to these methods can be Unicode strings or 8-bit
>   strings. 8-bit strings will be converted to Unicode before carrying
>   out the operation; Python’s default ASCII encoding will be used, so
>   characters greater than 127 will cause an exception

From [Re Doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> This module provides regular expression matching operations similar to
>   those found in Perl. Both patterns and strings to be searched can be
>   Unicode strings as well as 8-bit strings.

Since for the Re module you are not explicitly specifying the Unicode flag, it is not attempting the conversion and hence not raising the error. That is why they aren't behaving coherently

Comment: Mhh. Not too coinvinced about the flag thing; >>> re.sub(u'è','\xe0','',flags=re.UNICODE) still gives me back ''

Comment: It is perfectly possible for the re module to be catching that exception and not being transparent about it, just a hunch, not confirmed.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( Python is absolutely horrible with unicode support. I've wasted 3 days now and still couldn't finish a super simple read-change-write function.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.X has a somewhat unnatural handling of encoding, which takes implicit conversion.  It will try to play with unicode and no-unicode strings, when conversion isn't taken care of by the user.  In the end, that doesn't solve the issue: encoding has to be acknowledged by the developer from the get-go.  Python 2 just makes things less explicit and a bit less obvious.

```
>>> u'è'.replace(u"\xe0", u"")
u'\xe8'
```

That's your original example, except, I specifically told Python that all strings were unicode.  If you don't, Python will try to convert them.  And because the default encoding in Python 2 is ASCII, that will obviously fail with your example.

Encoding is a tricky subject, but with some good habits (like early conversion, always being sure of what type of data is handled by the program at a given point), it usually (and I insist, USUALLY) goes well.

Hope that helps!